# How to quickly separate models？

Tags: edit-mode

I had a model, but it was merged into one. I could go through the step-by-step separation of models by checking the connected items, but this is inefficient. Is there a way or a plugin that can identify how many connected items there are with one click and then separate them with one click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how they're merged, you can go into edit mode, press 'A' to select everything, then press F3 and search for "Separate > By Loose Parts" and it will separate all objects whose meshes aren't connect.

[image]

[image]